# Haskell: Default empty fields to value

Tags: haskell

When constructing an instance using `Pattern {}` in Haskell you must define all fields.

A lot of the time I find myself filling most of these fields with some default value, usually the same as the values in `mempty` if I have defined `monoid`.

Is there any syntax in Haskell to construct an instance using `{}` but defaulting to the fields of another instance if not present.

Something like `mempty with {...}`.

Comment: The diagrams library does this as sort of an "optional arguments" pattern. Instead of `rectangle defX defY 3 defH` you use [`with`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.5.1/docs/Diagrams-Util.html#v:with) to supply the defaults and override the arguments you want to be non-default, as in `rectangle with { width = 3 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variable with the other instance in place of the data constructor, like this: `mempty{ someField = 123 }`.